# Falso Positivo MongoDB UniqueValidator

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

tengo un problemita con MongoDB en node, la cosa es que estoy haciendo un backend para un sistema de gestión y al querer crear un nuevo DEVICE en el modelo devices. El unique validator me esta devolviendo como que ya existen todos los campos, el _id, el serial y el company_id. Cuando en realidad la collection se encuentra vacía.

Este es mi `deviceModel`:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var deviceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    serial: { 
        type: String, 
        required: [true, "Serial no puede estar en blanco"],
        index: true
    },
    brand: { 
        type: String, 
        required: [true, "Marca no puede estar en blanco"]
    },
    model: { 
        type: String, 
        required: [true, "Modelo no puede estar en blanco"]
    },
    description: String,
    company_alias: { 
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
},
{
    timestamps: true
});

deviceSchema.index({ serial: 1, company_alias: 1}, { unique: true });
deviceSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, {message: 'El equipo ya existe'});

var Device = module.exports = mongoose.model('device', deviceSchema);
module.exports.get = function (callback, limit) {
    Device.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

DeviceController:

```js
exports.new = function (req, res) {
    var device = new Device();
    
    let data = req.body;
    device.brand = data.brand;
    device.model = data.model;
    device.description = data.description;
    device.company_alias = data.company_alias;
    device.serial = data.serial;

   
    device.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                success: false,
                message: err
            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Nuevo equipo ingresado!',
                data: device
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Y este es el error que me da mongo al intentar ingresar cualquier device nuevo

```js
{
    "success": false,
    "message": {
        "errors": {
            "company_alias": {
                "message": "El equipo ya existe",
                "name": "ValidatorError",
                "properties": {
                    "message": "El equipo ya existe",
                    "type": "unique",
                    "path": "company_alias",
                    "value": "5f41fa3b9ca31b092caf2e8d",
                    "reason": {}
                },
                "kind": "unique",
                "path": "company_alias",
                "value": "5f41fa3b9ca31b092caf2e8d",
                "reason": {}
            },
            "serial": {
                "message": "El equipo ya existe",
                "name": "ValidatorError",
                "properties": {
                    "message": "El equipo ya existe",
                    "type": "unique",
                    "path": "serial",
                    "value": "KJN2418964ASD",
                    "reason": {}
                },
                "kind": "unique",
                "path": "serial",
                "value": "KJN2418964ASD",
                "reason": {}
            },
            "_id": {
                "message": "El equipo ya existe",
                "name": "ValidatorError",
                "properties": {
                    "message": "El equipo ya existe",
                    "type": "unique",
                    "path": "_id",
                    "value": "5f5ab8ecefc4063c405ded1c",
                    "reason": {}
                },
                "kind": "unique",
                "path": "_id",
                "value": "5f5ab8ecefc4063c405ded1c",
                "reason": {}
            }
        },
        "_message": "device validation failed",
        "message": "device validation failed: company_alias: El equipo ya existe, serial: El equipo ya existe, _id: El equipo ya existe",
        "name": "ValidationError"
    }
}
```

Es como si el validator estuviera haciendo un falso positivo o algo así y no se porque, recuerdo que mongodb tenia como un caché o algo por el estilo, pero ando un poco olvidado y no recuerdo si alguna vez me ocurrio algo parecido como lo solucioné, se agradece una mano.

Comment: Solo por probar, cambia el nombre del campo `model` por otro como por ejemplo: `mdl` o `_model`, tanto en el esquema como al crear un nuevo documento, obviamente. Comenta el resultado. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intente el comentario del colega y esa fue la solución.

> Solo por probar, cambia el nombre del campo model por otro como por ejemplo: mdl o _model, tanto en el esquema como al crear un nuevo documento.